# Missing padding for S column in tabularx

Tags: tables, siunitx

I am trying to create a table that has a filling column in between. However, my last column (an S type) has not padding on the right side for reasons I do not understand.

Here a MWE

```
    \documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{textcase}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}
\newcommand*{\tableheadline}[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{\textsc{\MakeTextLowercase{#1}}}}

\begin{table}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{lS[round-mode=places,round-precision=2]XlS[round-mode=places,round-precision=2]} \toprule
      \tableheadline{\MakeTextLowercase{Variable}} & \tableheadline{Value in }\si{eV} & & \tableheadline{Variable} & \tableheadline{Value in }\si{eV}\\ \midrule
      $E_A$ &  0. & & $E_C$ &  0.\\
    $J$  &  0.  & & $\xi$ &  0.0\\
    $t_1$ &  0. & & $t_2$ & -0.0\\
      \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is nothing to do with `siunitx` or with `tabularx`: it's your use of `\tableheadline`. You've defined that to include a `\multicolumn` as well as a case change, then put additional header material *after* it (`\si{eV}`). That text is then 'dangling' and not properly handled by the alignment. If you want to keep `\tableheadline` with the current definition then use `\NoCaseChange` on parts to be protected from the case function:

```
\tableheadline{Value in \NoCaseChange{\si{eV}}}
```

Alternatively, you could separate out the `\mulicolumn` and font/text change parts.